# Check that web element has class with pseudo selector (:first-child) applied using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: css, selenium

I have a css style that uses pseudo selector `first-child`:

```
.point:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Is there a way to check that some particular DOM element has class `point` with `:first-child` pseudo-selector applied?
`.getAttribute("class")` will not work, it will just return `"point"`

Answer (score 0):

CSS Pseudo-classes will be available in the element itself but on the css section only.
Try using this selector `".point:first"` on JQuery selector